# How to show data in grid view in another page on click of button in previous button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using these code to open details in another page on click of search button in previous page.
Is there any other alternative for these.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "Window.Open('Search_Advance.aspx','_blank');", true);
```

Comment: on click of a button in previous button or page??

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp:LinkButton for this. Set PostBackUrl to you page name. in this case

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkBtn1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Search_Advance.aspx" Text="Search"></asp:LinkButton>
```

on click of this button it ll go to tht page. and you can bind the gridview there.

Comment: here Its going to other page but it not showing data in page. con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SEARCH", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter property_id = cmd.Parameters.Add("@City_Id", DropDownList4.SelectedValue.ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);Session["sessDataSet"] = ds;
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "Window.Open('Search_Basic.aspx','_blank');", true);

Comment: in that page, you need to bind data to gridview. then only data ll be shown. you can use querystring/session for transfering any info like Id to other page. in page_Load() u need to bind data to gridview

Comment: This event is not firing onclick  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {     con.Open(); DataSet ds = new DataSet();  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ADVSERCH", con);    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter property_id12 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City_Id", DropDownList14.SelectedValue.ToString());
            SqlParameter property_id11 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", DropDownList4.SelectedValue.ToString());SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds); Session["sessDataSet1"] = ds;

Comment: this is very simple. Bt it was not understandable of what exactly u were lookin for by tht question. now i understood in one pae you are getin data from database and storing in session... after soring u need to redirect to another page like Response.Write("Search_Basic.aspx");

Comment: And in that page u need to get the datatable from session and bind to gridview

Comment: simple redirecting to another page has multiple ways. u need to ask your objective clearly

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("connection Strin");
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SEARCH", con); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City_Id",DropDownList4.SelectedValue.ToString());
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(ds);
Session["sessDataSet"] = ds; 
Response.Redirect("Search_Basic.aspx");
```

then in Search_Basic.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
   DataSet ds=(DataSet)Session["sessDataSet"];
   GridViewId.DataSource=ds;
   GridViewId.DataBind();
}
```